# A way to express that less expertise in a field is necessary to achieve similar results?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am a student mastering in machine learning. When I read papers describing older 
machine learning algorithms and frameworks, I often see that a lot of very advanced domain knowledge is poured into these methods. When looking at newer methods, a lot of that specific knowledge is no longer directly needed as newer machine learning models learn more complex representations than before. A great deal of the engineering is replaced by statistical models.

What would be a phrase (or word) to describe that one can achieve today better or similar results than one with more domain knowledge could have years ago?

Example of a sentence:

> The method presented in [paper 1] {insert comparison here} [paper 2]. Indeed, the authors show improved performance while alleviating the need for complex engineered feature extraction methods.

For example, "is easier than" could work but it does not carry a scientific tone nor does it specify what makes it easier (even though that is understood from the following sentence).

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence where this would be used? It's a requirement for phrase/word requests.

Comment: Thank you for asking. The bad news is that this is the wrong place for your question. This site is about the English language itself: word meanings, pronunciation, spelling, grammar, history. Check out “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)” Or one of these sites might be helpful: [academia.se], [writers.se], [literature.se]. If you are learning English, take a look at [ell.se]. If you want to try another site, please ask for migration, or else delete here before re-asking the question on the other site. See: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think your sentence is describing the old knowledge as *no longer needed*, or *unnecessary* to solve the current problem. Less kind terms would be *archaic* or *obsolete*.

It would be interesting to know if the older knowledge was truly never needed to get to the current state of the art. If this were the case it would seem to belong to a different subject.